# Is there a way to pick RAW images using react-native-image-picker

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-image-picker

I have an app which lets the user upload media (image/video).
The problem I'm facing is that when I try to select an image which has a format of RAW/Apple ProRAW (you can click RAW photos on iPhone 12 Pro and later Pro models with iOS 14.3 or later).
It does nothing and no image is selected

Any other image format is being selected (PNG/JPG).
Only when I try to select a RAW image, it does nothing.

"react-native-image-picker": "^4.10.2",